# JQuery closest() selector not working

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I'm writing a small coffeescript to delete a list from HTML. This is my sample HTML:

```
<li class="picture col-xs-3" id="picture_38">
 <div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="/system/uploads/picture/image/38/thumb_ASUS_EeePadMeMo_2.jpg">
  <div class="caption">
   <a class="btn red btn-xs img_action_remove" data-method="delete" data-remote="true"   href="/admin/galleries/3/pictures/38" rel="nofollow" title="Remove">
    Delete
   </a>
  </div>
 </div>
</li>
```

I have several li items, and I need to delete the list item when i click on the link with `img_action_remove` tag. Here is my script:

```
$ ->
  $('.img_action_remove').bind 'ajax:success', (event, data, status, xhr) ->
    $(this).closest('li').remove()
```

For me it looks fine, but I'm sure that I wrong something traversing the DOM.

Comment: You're sure the link isn't actually navigating to the page in the href, and that `this` inside the event handler is the element.

Comment: Can you fix the example to be properly code formatted? It's really goofy looking ;)

Comment: where does the event `ajax:success` come from?

Comment: It's an ajax call to delete the picture from the db. The call is working... if I reload the page the image is disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the link is navigating to the href specified, what you need to do add click handler to link with class `img_action_remove` and use

```
$(".img_action_remove").click (e)->
  e.preventDefault(); //then your functionality
```

Check this fiddle, have implemented in jquery http://jsfiddle.net/u49zq/